# Wordpress Bootstrap Menu - Blur content when collapsed

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav, blur

I have a Bootstrap menu in Wordpress like this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

I am using a version 3.0.3 "bootstrap.min.js" file. I would like to know how to blur the page content once the nav collapses, removing blur after hiding. I am already using a transparent background for the nav when collapses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new div set to position:absolute and size of the whole page.

Add the blur effect to its class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. According to your suggestion, won't be the burry effect permanent? How to show and hide the blurry effect at the same time the nav menu collapses and hides?